# How do I disable Microsoft Edge Updater?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge, background

When I end task it on task manager it opens up 15 minutes later. I don’t need a web browser I don’t use to be updating every minute of the day, slowing down my computer.

I mean MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Windows 10 1909 Users

The following will work in Windows 10 1909 if you run it in command prompt as administrator.

```
sc config "edgeupdate" start=disabled

sc config "edgeupdatem" start=disabled
```

That part of the instructions is wrong as it no longer works in newer versions of Windows 10 like 20H2.

In short Windows doesn't allow you to turn the Microsoft Edge Updating Service off the typical way, like if you went to Computer Management, services.msc Services Management Console or msconfig System Configuration, so more obscure methods of turning it off have to be used.

Those commands were a command line way of doing something that can be done in a graphical user interface, to dictate how the 2 microsoft edge services start,but it appears that Microsoft made those settings useless in newer versions of Windows 10. Windows provides 4 options.

- Automatic
- Automatic (delayed)
- Inactive
- Disabled

See this image.

[image: windows services change startup type]

## Windows 10 20H2 Users

Changing the startup setting of the 2 microsoft edge services to `disabled` doesn't work in Windows 20H2 as Microsoft made Windows override it anyway. So you'll have to do more unconventional methods.

Check these threads

- [Disable Installation of Microsoft Edge by Windows Update in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/146650-disable-installation-microsoft-edge-windows-update-windows-10-a.html)
- [How Can I Stop Microsoft Edge from Updating](https://www.tenforums.com/browsers-email/168354-how-can-i-stop-microsoft-edge-updating-2.html)

Below is the method I used.

Open command prompt as administrator then run the following commands.

```
taskkill /im MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe /f
rd "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate" /s /q
```

Then you need to also delete the following registry keys in RegEdit or Registry Editor (along with deleting the EdgeUpdate files and tasks):

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\edgeupdate
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\edgeupdatem
```

Answer (score 0):

## Disable Microsoft Edge Auto Update (Windows Powershell Script)

**The script must be executed from an administrative prompt access**

```
Write-Host "Disabling browser auto update..."

$msEdgeInstallationPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft'

$Process2Monitor = "MicrosoftEdgeUpdate"; 
For ($i = 0; $i -lt 5; $i++) {
    $ProcessesFound = Get-Process | ? { $Process2Monitor -contains $_.Name } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name; If ($ProcessesFound) { "Microsoft Edge updater running... Killing it" | Write-Host; Stop-Process -Name $Process2Monitor -Force; Break } else { "Microsoft Edge updater not running. Retrying in 1 second..." | Write-Host; Start-Sleep -Seconds 1} 
}

Write-Host "Waiting for Microsoft Edge update to finish (60s Timeout)"

For ($i = 0; $i -lt 60; $i++) {
    $ProcessesFound = Get-Process | ? { $Process2Monitor -contains $_.Name } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name; If ($ProcessesFound) { "Microsoft Edge updater running... waiting its finish..." | Write-Host; Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 } else { "Microsoft Edge updater finished." | Write-Host; Break}
}

Rename-Item -Path "$msEdgeInstallationPath\EdgeUpdate\MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe" -NewName MicrosoftEdgeUpdateDisabled.exe -Force
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple run on the `cmd` the following command as administrator to disable Microsoft Edge auto update. **The requirement is that the user must be associated to a domain**.

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate /v UpdateDefault /t REG_DWORD /f /d 0x00000000
```

The advantage of this method is that there is no need to delete the MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe.

Comment: [That particular policy is only applicable to systems connected to an Active Domain directory.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-update-policies#updatedefault)

Comment: Yeah @Ramhound it's right. I updated the answer with this requirement.